# How to modify field values with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm new to AOP with AspectJ and I need to write the following simple aspect:

I have the `@EndDay`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface EndDay { }
```

annotation and I need to intercept all non-reflective assignation to all non-static fields of the type `Date` annotated with `@EndDate` annotation and then assign the value of the end of the day specified in the assigned `Date` object (e.g we're assigngn `2011-11-11 10:00:00`, it's intercepted and assigned `2011-11-11 23:59:59` instead). 
What I have tried:

```
public aspect EndDay {
    before(): set(@DayEnd private Date *) {
        Date d = (Date) thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
        DateUtils.setDayEnd(d); //It an utility class modifying the date
    };
}
```

It didn't work properly. How can I fix that?

Comment: Just to make sure you are certain the aspect is weave and called during execution?

Comment: @AleksiYrttiaho I've already found a solution :)

Comment: Great! Could you please write your own answer and accept it? I was just considering polishing my aspect skills.

Comment: @AleksiYrttiaho Sure, just a second.

Comment: @AleksiYrttiaho Done. Couldn't you correct me if I was wrong someweher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the value being assigned to a field we need to use the `around` advice, instead of `before` or `after`. The around advice specifies that we will perform some operations ***instead*** of ones being performed normally. Now, as the [documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) says:

> All set join points are treated as having one argument, the value the
>   field is being set to, so at a set join point, that value can be
>   accessed with an args pointcut.

That means we should have declared our advice for the conjucntion of the `set(@DayEnd private Date *)` and `args(original)`. The first one picks out all the private fields assignments, but the second one specifying the value being assigned. Now, in order to assign the moified value we finally need to call `proceed(_modified_argument)`.

The working aspect looks as follows:

```
public aspect DayBoundaries {

   void around(Date original): set(@DayEnd private Date *) && args(original){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(original);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
        proceed(c.getTime());
    };
}
```

Comment: What a well written answer, thank you! I suspect you should be able to alter the `Date` instance provided as a parameter using the `before` advice but this does not cause a side effect.

Comment: Please accept your own answer in order to close the question. Some people around here look for open questions in order to answer them. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @kriegaex I can do that in 1 day.